# python MySQL insert big data

Tags: python, mysql

using python,I am looping through csv file to read data, then I am ding some modifications on the readied row and call a save function to insert the modified data into MySQL.

```
def save(Id, modifiedData,):
    try:
       mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="use",password="pass",database="data")
       sql = "INSERT INTO data (Id, modifiedData)  VALUES (%s, %s)"
       recordTuple = (Id, modifiedData)
       mycursor = mydb.cursor()
       mycursor.execute(sql,recordTuple)
       mydb.commit()
       print("Record inserted successfully into table")

    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Failed to insert into MySQL table {}".format(error))

def main():
            for row in csv:    
             #modify row 
             #creat Id
             save(Id, modifiedData,)
```

but  I don't think this is good solution to do MYSQL connection and insert data with each iteration, it will be time and resources consuming , specially when I move to real server in production
how can I improve my solution?

Comment: Accumulate the modified data in a buffer, and send many values to MySQL at once (when the number of values reaches a certain limit, for example, 1000 rows, or when all rows are processed) in a single query. For example, with `cursor.executemany`.

Comment: The fastest way to do this is to save the modified data in a new csv then use a "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ..." statement

Comment: @ChechyLevas This needs (1) the place accessable for both PHP and MySQL exists (2) LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INFILE allowed on MySQL.

Comment: @Akina fair point. But if those 2 conditions are satisfied then this will most performant. For very large csv files, might be worth pursuing.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, connections should be managed by connection pool, should be committed bulky. But amount of csv at most, need not to mind so much. Anyway, If you don't wanna bother it, I recommend using ORM like [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You only need to create the connection once, and that should be in function `main`, who then passes the connection to function `save` as follows:

```
def save(mydb, Id, modifiedData):
    try:
       sql = "INSERT INTO data (Id, modifiedData)  VALUES (%s, %s)"
       recordTuple = (Id, modifiedData)
       mycursor = mydb.cursor()
       mycursor.execute(sql,recordTuple)
       mydb.commit()
       print("Record inserted successfully into table")
    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Failed to insert into MySQL table {}".format(error))

def main():
    try:
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="use",password="pass",database="data")
    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Failed to create connection: {}".format(error))
        return            
    for row in csv:    
         #modify row 
         #creat Id
         save(mydb, Id, modifiedData)
```

For perhaps even greater performance you can try `executemany`:

```
def save(mydb, modified_records):
    try:
       sql = "INSERT INTO data (Id, modifiedData)  VALUES (%s, %s)"
       mycursor = mydb.cursor()
       mycursor.executemany(sql, modified_records)
       mydb.commit()
       print("Records inserted successfully into table")
    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Failed to insert into MySQL table {}".format(error))

def main():
    try:
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="use",password="pass",database="data")
    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Failed to create connection: {}".format(error))
        return
    modified_records = []
    for row in csv:    
        #modify row 
        #creat Id
        modified_records.append([id, modifiedData])
    save(mydb, modified_records)
```